# Unresolved compilation but library already in classpath

Tags: java

I'm facing a very weird problem trying to build this component:

https://github.com/theclue/talend-components-collection/tree/master/twitter/tTwitterStreamInput

this is a custom component for Talend Open Studio, actually, but the problem seems more general and it's not related to Talend.

the unresolved compilation problems are related to 2 classes located in twitter4j-stream-4.0.1.jar

the library is correctly imported and linked, as you may see from the command I use to execute it:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -verbose -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/guava-13.0.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/talend-bridge-api-0.2.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/tTwitterStreamInput-1.1.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/twitter-commodities-0.2.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/twitter4j-stream-4.0.1.jar;.;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/classes;E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib; test.twitterstream_0_1.twitterStream
```

but the exeception leaves no doubt:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method addListener(StatusListener) from the type TalendRowTweetBehaviour refers to the missing type StatusListener
    The method addFilter(FilterQuery) from the type TalendRowTweetBehaviour refers to the missing type FilterQuery

    at test.twitterstream_0_1.twitterStream.tTwitterStreamInput_1Process(twitterStream.java:737)
    at test.twitterstream_0_1.twitterStream.tTwitterOAuth_1Process(twitterStream.java:429)
    at test.twitterstream_0_1.twitterStream.runJobInTOS(twitterStream.java:1241)
    at test.twitterstream_0_1.twitterStream.main(twitterStream.java:1100)
```

Using the -verbose command line parameter I can check the loaded classes. Effectively, StatusListener and FilterQuery are NOT loaded. But I've no clue on WHY thery are not, since the library is available and explicited in the classpath!

EDIT: I added a screenshot for better clarity. I'm wondering why the unresolved class is declared at line 733 but the error is at line 737 only...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the Twitter jar is declared as `E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/tTwitterStreamInput-1.1.jar`. You sure about that small 't' at the beginning? It seems that java can't find the JAR due to a wrong filename.

Comment: nono, tTwitterStreamInput is my library (it's a tiny wrapper, actually). The similar name is just a coincidence, it's not the same .jar

Comment: My bad. I noticed you specified the particular JAR file that is having problems. Can you try to do `jar tf E:/TalendWorkspaces/.Java/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar` and see if you can find `StatusListener` and `FilterQuery`? Note that this may print out a lot of lines so you have to keep your eyes sharp (or use `grep` or suchlike).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by doing a `maven clean`.

This is not a real answer, though, since I didn't figure why this weird behaviour happened